# What are the ways to heal after casting a levelled spell as an action in the same round?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, healing, action-economy

### Context

Following [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/172371/can-you-cast-two-spells-from-a-ring-of-spell-storing-during-the-same-round-using), I am looking for ways to heal (self and/or others) in the same round after casting [Beacon of Hope](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/beacon-of-hope) from a [Ring of Spell Storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing).

I was looking for an abilty like a Divine Channel or an item I could use to heal but didn't find anything. (and I don't really know where to search besides Google and the Stackexchange)

**Sidenote**: I am a level 5 cleric of Qotal (Life) but I'm also interested to know how other classes could do.

Comment: "Cleric of Qotal" doesn't mean much; domain is more relevant that deity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Healing Others

Healing others as a bonus action (since you already spent your action casting) without spells seem fairly rare. Here are some examples I could find, though none are Cleric features unfortunately:

1. Oath of the Crown Paladin's [Turn the Tide](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/paladin#ChannelDivinity-498):

   > As a bonus action, you can bolster injured creatures with your Channel Divinity. Each creature of your choice that can hear you within 30 feet of you regains hit points equal to 1d6 + your Charisma modifier (minimum of 1) if it has no more than half of its hit points.
2. Circle of Dreams Druid's [Balm of the Summer Court](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#BalmoftheSummerCourt-662):

   > As a bonus action, you can choose one creature you can see within 120 feet of you and spend a number of those dice equal to half your druid level or less. Roll the spent dice and add them together. The target regains a number of hit points equal to the total. The target also gains 1 temporary hit point per die spent.
3. Celestial Warlock's [Healing Light](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#HealingLight-608):

   > (...) You have a pool of d6s that you spend to fuel this healing. The number of dice in the pool equals 1 + your warlock level. As a bonus action, you can heal one creature you can see within 60 feet of you, spending dice from the pool.
4. A Purple Dragon Knight Fighter's [Rallying Cry](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#RallyingCry-484) also works since it happens when the Fighter uses Second Wind which is a bonus action, though since the healing is fixed, it does not benefit from Beacon of Hope (though the Second Wind itself would):

   > When you use your Second Wind feature, you can choose up to three creatures within 60 feet of you that are allied with you. Each one regains hit points equal to your fighter level, provided that the creature can see or hear you.
5. A Thief Rogue using [Fast Hands](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#FastHands-364) with the Healer feat and a Healing Kit (see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122850/33707) for details)

### Self healing

1. Any Fighter's [Second Wind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#SecondWind-192):

   > On your turn, you can use a bonus action to regain hit points equal to 1d10 + your fighter level
2. Oath of Redemption Paladin's [Protective Spirit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/paladin#ProtectiveSpirit-714)

   > You regain hit points equal to 1d6 + half your paladin level if you end your turn in combat with fewer than half of your hit points remaining and you aren’t incapacitated.
3. Divine Soul Sorcerer's [Unearthly Recovery](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#UnearthlyRecovery-749), though it isn't boosted by Beacon of Hope.

   > As a bonus action when you have fewer than half of your hit points remaining, you can regain a number of hit points equal to half your hit point maximum
4. Undying Patron Warlock's [Indestructible Life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#IndestructibleLife-522):

   > On your turn, you can use a bonus action to regain hit points equal to 1d8 + your warlock level.

Comment: I don't see OP mentioning "healing others" specifically, it's just about healing in general. Any particular reason you focused on that aspect of healing?

Comment: @PixelMaster That's actually a good point, for some reason I assumed OP was looking to heal others but it's not actually stated, this does open up some more options I'm sure, I'll go take another look.

Comment: Hidden further down in a (partial) answer is the idea of action surge which would add value to this answer imho.

Comment: @findusl That's the whole idea for that answer so I'd rather go upvoting that other answer in this case

Answer (score 7):

## Healing Spells are at least first level, so you cannot use those

You cannot use healing word because it is not a cantrip. The paladins aura of healing heals as a bonus action - no casting in the same turn necessary, but unfortunately, it requires concentration which you need for beacon of hope. There are no healing Cantrips.

## Potion house rule

I heard, some people allow drinking a potion of healing as a bonus action through a house rule. You should ask your GM about this.

## Take one level of fighter

If you are allowed to multiclass, you can take a level of fighter which will give you access to second wind.

## Hand of Vecna

The artifact hand of Vecna heals you by 1d10 hit points per turn without using spells or consuming an action.

Comment: I love this answer... you can buy an item, dip a level, or utilize a crazy artifact that may warp your personality and adventure entirely!

Answer (score 4):

#### Have two levels of fighter.

2nd level fighters have action surge which grants them a second action. Noting the rules explained in [this question and answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133767/62294), if you use action surge after casting a leveled spell with a casting time of 1 action, you may cast another leveled spell with a casting time of 1 action as long as you have not used you bonus action to cast a spell (leveled *or* cantrip).