# Does it take an action or an object interaction to pull a stirge from your neck?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, actions

The "Interacting with Objects Around You" sidebar on PHB p. 190 (or [here in the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#InteractingwithObjectsAroundYou)) says:

> Here are a few examples of the sorts of thing you can do in tandem
>   with your movement and action:
>
> - draw or sheathe a sword

**Would pulling a stirge attached to your neck count as "interacting with an object", or would it take an actual action?**

Comment: Please do not use code formatting for anything except actual code fragments, things that are for a computer to read more than a person. Misuse of code formatting can make it more difficult for alternative browsing technologies, like screen readers for the blind, to make sense of the site, and so can make the site less accessible and welcoming to those users who rely on them. See [this meta discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3086/4563) for more details.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### It's an action, because the Stirge's monster description says so

As per the creature's entry in the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/stirge):

> A creature, including the target, can use its action to detach the stirge.

You have to use your action to detach the Stirge.

Answer (score 13):

### A stirge is a creature [not an object](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95532/41726)

The specific action to remove a stirge...

> A creature, including the target, can use its action to detach the stirge.

... is not [covered by the Use an Object](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49825/41726) action (**emphasis** mine)

> When **an object** requires your action for its use, you take the Use an Object action.