# What are all the published objects that require the Use an Object action?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, equipment

**I am looking for an exhaustive list of all objects that can be used with the Use an Object action.** RAW, official printed material only.

Depending on what falls in under the Use an Object action, the thief (sub class of rogue) could either be very good or nearly useless.

In [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72270/what-items-can-a-thief-use-as-a-bonus-action-with-his-fast-hands) I found a list saying that the following items all require the use of an action in their descriptions:

> - Acid
> - Alchemist's Fire
> - Ball Bearings
> - Caltrops
> - Climber's Kit
> - Healer's Kit
> - Holy Water
> - Hunting Trap
> - Lantern, Hooded
> - Oil
> - Poison, Basic
> - Tinderbox

Is that all?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95148/discussion-on-question-by-ragatokk-what-are-all-the-published-objects-that-requi).

Comment: The question of whether this question is a duplicate or not is being discussed in [this Meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9215/why-is-this-question-a-duplicate).

Comment: Strongly Related on [What does Use an Object cover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49825/what-does-use-an-object-cover) and [What items can a thief use as a bonus action with his fast hands?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72270/what-items-can-a-thief-use-as-a-bonus-action-with-his-fast-hands)

Comment: I would argue "too broad" because of the "all published" part of the question. This would include every custom magical and non-magical item not just in the existing books, but also every new book, every new adventure. Even if it would be possible to round up all the answers to this as of now, the answer would change every few months as new content is created. This seems like too large a task for a simple question and answer. I think the scope should be limited to a specific, non-growing set.

Comment: @AgentPaper I am pretty sure it would not include any magic items, custom or otherwise as they do not use the use an object action.

Comment: I'm voting to close as Too Broad. Since new books with new Use an Object actions come out all the time, this is a list question with an unknown scope. Any answers to this question will be made obselete as soon as another book comes out. The question could be made not Too Broad if you specified a specific list of books you're interested in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This is the answer that you want to read.*

For this list I have compiled all objects that specify that they take an action to use. This list excludes magical items and objects that don't explicitly state that they take an action to use (like tools and objects that require an ability check instead, etc.).

> **Use an Object**
>
> You normally interact with an object while doing something else, such
>   as when you draw a sword as part of an attack. When an object requires
>   your action for its use, you take the Use an Object action. This
>   action is also useful when you want to interact with more than one
>   object on your turn.

This makes it distinct that all normal interaction that doesn't require an action is handled by Other Activity on Your Turn (PHB 190) and similar sections in the rules. Note that "useful" doesn't mean that you can use objects that don't require an action for the Use an Object action.

Other Activity on Your Turn (PHB 190):

> Your turn can include a variety of flourishes that require neither
>   your action nor your move.
>
> If you want to interact with a second object, you need to use your
>   action. Some magic items and other special objects always require an
>   action to use, as stated in their descriptions.

See here that you can use your action to interact with a second action, but that that action is distinct from the Use an Object action which is for objects that require your action.

Activating an Item (DMG 141):

> Activating some magic items requires a user to do something special,
>   such as holding the item and uttering a command word. The description
>   of each item category or individual item details how an item is
>   activated. Certain items use one or more of the following rules for
>   their activation. If an item requires an action to activate, that
>   action isn't a function of the Use an Item action, so a feature such
>   as the rogue's Fast Hands can't be used to activate the item.

The thereby excluded magical item actions are definitive all magical items with the properties: Command Word, Consumables, Spells and Charges. A very well-versed rules lawyer could argue that all other magic item actions fall under the Use an Object action because the kind of property of activation is defined by these four terms. For the sake of sanity, I will exclude all magical items, even those that may be lawyered into the eligible pool for the Use an Object action. I wouldn't allow this lawyering anyway.

Fast Hands (PHB 97):

> Starting at 3rd level, you can use the bonus action granted by your
>   Cunning Action to make a Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check, use your
>   thieves’ tools to disarm a trap or open a lock, or take the Use an
>   Object action.

### The list:

[Ball Bearings (bag of 1,000)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/ball-bearings-bag-of-1-000)

[Bomb](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/bomb)

[Caltrops (bag of 20)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/caltrops-bag-of-20)

[Climber's Kit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/climbers-kit)

[Dynamite (Stick)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/dynamite-stick)

[Grenade Launcher](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/grenade-launcher)

[Grenade, Fragmentation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/grenade-fragmentation)

[Grenade, Smoke](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/grenade-smoke)

[Healer's Kit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/healers-kit)

[Hunting Trap](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/hunting-trap)

[Lantern, Hooded](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/lantern-hooded)

[Poison, Basic (vial)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/poison-basic-vial)

[Tangler Grenade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/tangler-grenade)

[Tinderbox](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/tinderbox)

### Things that notably aren't on the list:

[Acid (vial)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/acid-vial), [Alchemist's Fire (flask)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/alchemists-fire-flask), [Holy Water (flask)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/holy-water-flask) and [Oil (flask)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/oil-flask) as an action all four require you to make a ranged attack. [Oil (flask)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/oil-flask) is an outliner because it specifies that you can pour it on the ground (but not that this takes an action). At your discretion, you may add these four to the list.

All ranged **firearm** weapons that have the Reload property can be reloaded, and you may use the Use an Object action for reloading (DMG 267):

> ***Reload.*** A limited number of shots can be made with a weapon that has the reload property. A character must then reload it using an
>   action or a bonus action (the character's choice).

All poisons other than the [Poison, Basic (vial)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/poison-basic-vial) don't specify that applying the poison takes an action.

All explosives, firearms and alien technologies are part of the DMGs Workshop and therefore optional content.

---

<sub>* Except for magical items that may be lawyered to fall under the Use an Object action.</sub>

Comment: I wonder, the [Bomb](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/bomb) would be allowed in AL, considering it is an "Renaissance Item".
I can not see the grenades being a viable item pretty much ever as it is a modern era item without a list price.

Comment: @Ragatokk I don't know AL rules, but that seems like a viable question to ask - Are Bombs (DMG 267) legal in AL play? Or are Explosives (DMG 267-268) legal in AL play?

Comment: I'll search around for a bit and ask the question if I can't find an answer.

Comment: @NautArch " as an action all four require you to make a ranged attack" "At your discretion, you may add these four to the list." Firearms are optional, that is correct.

Comment: Up to you if you want to have it in there at all(because it's for an unrelated optional rule), but you may also want to see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72270/what-items-can-a-thief-use-as-a-bonus-action-with-his-fast-hands) about using Use an Object action for an attack vs an attack action.

Comment: @NautArch most books are entirely optional. The only rules are PH(B), MM, and the DMG (See SA Compendium), generally I do not exclude optional content based on not being set rules. I know the question and think that the 4 items are edge cases - one may list them.

Comment: @NautArch I think that one could reasonably rule that way, but it is an edge case, and therefore it is on the notable section. All things mentioned in that section have a strong enough case going for them, and one should have a gander at them take note and possibly include them.

Answer (score 6):

## This won't be the answer you want to hear

I know you're asking "for an exhaustive list of all objects that can be used with the Use an Object action", but I don't think you realize just how extensive that list would be.

The items you've listed are all items with descriptions specifically requiring an action to use. Per DMG page 141,

> If an item requires an action to activate, that action isn't a function of the Use an Object action, so a feature such as the rogue's Fast Hands can't be used to activate the item.

However, this is stated specifically in the DMG's description of how to use a magic item, so it is likely that this is talking about magic items rather than items in general.

This is supported by the definition of the Use an Object action in the PHB page 193.

> **Use an Object**
>
> You normally interact with an object while doing something else, such as when you draw a sword as part of an attack. When an object requires your action for its use, you take the Use an Object action. This action is also useful when you want to interact with more than one object on your turn.

Since at least some of the items you listed are non-magical items that require an action to use, they explicitly fall under the domain of the Use an Object action.

On page 190 of the PHB, under "Other Activity on Your Turn", it says

> You can also interact with one object... for free, *during either your move or your action* [emphasis mine].

Couple this with the line from page 193 that says, "This action is also useful when you want to interact with more than one object on your turn," and it becomes hard to argue that Use an Object *requires* the object to necessitate an action in its description, since "interact with an object" is clearly not limited by that.

## What does this mean?

This means that the list you are looking for will encompass *literally everything in every source material* that isn't a magic item, since *all* of it can be interacted with through the Use an Object action.

This site generally doesn't provide lists, and requests for lists are also generally not encouraged. Take note that the list you found was a list of examples provided as part of a question, and that none of the linked questions' answers incorporated any sort of lists at all. You probably won't be getting that list from here.

## About the Thief interaction

I think this is a case of "Specific beats general" where the general rule is that the Use an Object action takes an action, and the specific rule is that Use an Object can be done as a bonus action. With that reading of the rule, that means that the Thief can do a Use an Object action as a bonus action, even if the object's description says it normally requires an action to use.

I could be wrong about this, but I think this ability works with anything that isn't a magic item, including those items that specifically state they need an action to use.

Comment: "I am looking for an exhaustive list of all objects that can be used with the Use an Object action." These objects do not explicitly need to state so in their descriptions.

Comment: To be fair though, the question's title is asking for all object's that *require* the Use an Object action. Since the body asks for all objects that *can* be used with that action, it's actually two different questions here. I should probably clarify that I answered the body of the question rather than the title. I chose that approach particularly because the body mentions the rule's interaction with the Thief archetype, so it looked to me that the body was probably the question OP actually wanted an answer to.

Comment: It was an interesting read, but not what the question asked for. I just want a list of the items that have a defined use that can be used with the use an object action in the books.

Comment: I believe "If an item requires an action to activate, that action isn't a function of the Use an Object action, so a feature such as the rogue's Fast Hands can't be used to activate the item." is in relation to magic items. Otherwise you would have an distinction between use and activate.

Comment: What is your logic for combining the explicit requires action text of Use an Object with the Other Activity on Your Turn text? I don't see the logical connection in your answer.

Comment: @Akixkisu The Other Activity on Your Turn text clarifies that you only get one free interaction during your turn, and the Use an Object text gives you a way to get a second (or in the Thief's case, even a third) such interaction during your turn.

Comment: @Ragatokk The body of your question asks for "all objects that *can* be used with the Use an Object action," which is a different question from the title's "objects that *require* the Use an Object action." I chose to answer the question in the body because of your inclusion of the thief class, for which it's more relevant what *can* be used with a Use an Object rather than what *must* be used through a Use an Object action. If the title is the question you want answered instead, it might be useful to edit the body to more closely reflect the question's title.

Comment: @MrSpudtastic When an object requires your action for its use, you take the Use an Object action. This action is also useful when you want to interact with more than one object on your turn.

This makes it distinct that all normal interaction that doesn't require an action is handled by Other Activity on Your Turn (PHB 190) and similar sections in the rules. Note that "useful" doesn't mean that you can use objects that don't require an action for the Use an Object action.

Comment: @Akixkisu You are correct, but that section also specifies that you only get one such interaction per turn. The Use an Object action explicitly gives you a way to get more than one such interaction per turn.

Comment: @MrSpudtastic you could throw 2 grenades for instance.